# Force images to synchronize from an iPhone to a Mac

Tags: iphone, photos.app

My sister in law would like to synchronize photos from her iPhone to her Mac.
When she connects the iPhone to her Mac, iTunes starts up but photos don't synchronize.

I tried taking a couple of photos and import them using iPhoto. The software did not detect any new photos. Although I can see a bunch of very recent photos on the iPhone, the most recent photos in the iPhoto collection are from last year.

I'd like to manually copy all the photos from the iPhone into her Mac and then re-synchronize the images. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually import photos from iPhone into iPhoto. Connect your iPhone, open iPhoto, select iPhone in the sidebar, and select all of the photos you want to import, then click Import.

If she has upgraded to iOS 6 and has an iCloud account, she can enable Photo Stream on both devices. This will synchronize photos and place them in monthly albums in iPhoto.

Enable Photo Stream on OS X:

```
System Preferences > iCloud > Photo Stream
```

Enable Photo Stream on iOS:

```
Settings > iCloud > Photo Stream
```